# How to only print the top 5 customers and their top 5 purchased products with their respective total sales?

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, data-analysis

I have tried this code

```
result = df1.groupby(["Customer Name","Product Name"])['Sales'].aggregate(np.sum).reset_index().sort_values('Sales',ascending = False).head(5)
```

result

```
ID Customer Name    Product Name    Sales

8567    Sean Miller     Cisco TelePresence System EX90 Videoconferenci...   22638.480
9165    Tamara Chand    Canon imageCLASS 2200 Advanced Copier   17499.950
7725    Raymond Buch    Canon imageCLASS 2200 Advanced Copier   13999.960
9487    Tom Ashbrook    Canon imageCLASS 2200 Advanced Copier   11199.968
4083    Hunter Lopez    Canon imageCLASS 2200 Advanced Copier   10499.970
```

I am not sure how to get the top 5 products with their respective sales.

Comment: `groupby("Product Name")`

Comment: Without sample data, there isn't really a way to help resolve this issue.  Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).